# Call local variable by name without eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem calling local variable by name in view. I render this part of code from other view with locals:

```
{ url: @event_url, size: 1, style: 1 }


- style_default = { col_md: 12, col_sm: 12}
- style_1 = { col_md: 3, col_sm: 4}
- style_2 = { ... }
```

and I want to call variable `style_X` depending on the local variable `style`, which is given during rendering. I tried three ways to solve this problem:

- using `eval`
- using `instance_variable_get`
- using a lot of `if` conditions

but I think that they are not good enough. Is there any solution or method that can call local variables by name?

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea. Why not use something like `styles={style_1: style_1, style_2: style_2}`, or better yet, just set `style` to the style you want?

Comment: My teamlead sad the same, and we a using hash now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) is used for getting the value of a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this locals: `{ url: @event_url, size: 1, style: "style_#{style}" }`.
Or use something like this `send(:style)`